# Oracle XE 18c impdp dump from 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, oracle18c, impdp, expdp

I have a dump file that is created using expdp from Oracle 19c (exported with version parameter 18). Is it even possible to import the dumpfile to an Oracle 18c XE database?
The structure and everything else from the 19c database is unknown to me. I just got the 13gb dumpfile.

While using impdp it says:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
```

**Thats it.**

In /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/alert_XE.log it says:

```
XEPDB1(3):DW00 started with pid=62, OS id=23288, wid=1, job SYSTEM.SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01
2020-12-09T15:25:55.364764+00:00
XEPDB1(3):Resize operation completed for file# 9, old size 266240K, new size 276480K
```

Is there a another logfile I don't know about?

Anyways, my command looks like this:

```
impdp user/password@localhost/xepdb1 DIRECTORY=import_dir DUMPFILE=dump.expdp nologfile=y version=18 full=y
```

Yes, the user is privileged to do so.
Yes, the import_dir is set with CREATE DIRECTORY and the user is also privileged to use this directory.

*I'm lost.*

edit: I used stackoverflow for many years now and this is my very first question since I'm NEW to oracle in general and as I stated above: I'm lost.

2nd edit:
It's still the same error even after I try to partially import the dump with parameters like tables=

Comment: So have you checked operating system permissions on the file system directory pointed to by the Oracle directory `import_dir` ?

Comment: The only mention of this error without any further information seems to be related to mismatched timezone version. Please check `Select name,value$ from props$ where name='DST_PRIMARY_TT_VERSION';` against both DBs, your 18XE will need at least a version as recent as the 19c DB. You should also check any log file in the log directory (which will default to the import directory)

Comment: there are more logs for data pump - for your user in the database there should be a scheduler job that was kicked off to do your import, and there are logs attached to that

Comment: @MarkStewart the permissions are already set to oracle, so y

Comment: @AndrewSayer I already did that! The version is 31 for both, 18c XE and 19c, which is the latest.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thanks, I'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your dump file is too big. Oracle XE has some limitations.

See the Oracle documentation:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html

Resources:

- Up to 12 GB of user data
- Up to 2 GB of database RAM
- Up to 2 CPU threads
- Up to 3 Pluggable Databases

Comment: Well, this is one possibility. Thank you very much. I'll try with a smaller dump.